# How do I prevent directed broadcast packets in Hyper-V using virtual network adapter

Tags: hyper-v, subnet

When I connect two physical subnets by using a Cisco Router, I can configure the router to disable directed broadcasts (that could be used for example to send Magic packets for waking up Computers even on different subnets).

When I have two virtual subnets connected with virtual Network Adapters using Hyper-V, is it possible to use for example port ACLs to disable directed broadcasts from being sent as well?

Comment: By "two virtual subnets" you mean different virtual switches tied to separate physical interfaces? If so, have you enabled IP forwarding (aka routing) between interfaces in your Windows Hyper-V instance either using a registry key or by installing the Remote Access role?